# Facebook graph API search query is not returning work field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I search using facebook graph API ( using this link ),

```
graph.facebook.com/search?q=chinmay patel&type=user&fields=name,id,username,work,
```

it never returns the work back. Here is the result I get,

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "100001500767227", 
      "username": "chinmayrp"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "100000896291228", 
      "username": "chinmay99"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "100003158872381", 
      "username": "chinmay.patel.9081"
    }, ..... 
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "1007030149", 
      "username": "CPoverLord"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "1150758330", 
      "username": "chinmay.patel.71"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Chinmay Patel", 
      "id": "100004835978500", 
      "username": "chinmay.patel.90834"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=name,id,username,work&q=chinmay patel&type=user&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=100004835978500"
  }
}
```

Am I missing anything? Let me know, if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`work` is not a public profile field. The user must either have your app installed and you issue `user_work_history` permission or the user is a friend of a user that installed the application and `friends_work_history` is issued.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: Totally makes sense, Thanks. I was under impression that if our app issues user_work_history and friends_work_history permissions for the user itself, we can access friend's work info. But, your answer clarified the confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi phwd, i want to retrive all users list who have name = "jothisrik". if i type facebook "jothisrik" i saw the person's list. if i am using fql or fbgraph search i am not getting users list i got empty data. the user "jothisrik" set  not allowing public search. is any way to get all users which may set or may not set the public search?